# Rails Active Record count associations

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite, activerecord

I've been trying everything I can find in the Rails Guides and here to count and order by the number of assciations between two models.

The Query in the controller:

```
  def top_mires
    @title = "Top Posts"
    @posts = Post.joins('INNER JOIN favorites ON posts.id = favorites.favorited_id').select('posts.*, COUNT(favorites.favorited_id) AS favorite_count').group('posts.id').order('favorite_count desc').limit(10)
    render 'favorite_posts/show'
  end
```

the models:

Post:

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  include PublicActivity::Common

  acts_as_taggable

  belongs_to :user
  has_many :comments
  has_many :favorites, as: :favorited

  default_scope -> { order(created_at: :desc) }

  mount_uploader :picture, PictureUploader

  validates :user_id, presence: true
  validates :post_type, presence: true
  validates :content, presence: true
```

Favorite:

```
class Favorite < ApplicationRecord
  include PublicActivity::Model
  tracked only: [:create], owner: :user, recipient: :favorited

  belongs_to :favorited, polymorphic: true, counter_cache: :favorite_count
  belongs_to :user
end
```

But I get back this error:

```
SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: favorite_count: SELECT  COUNT(*) AS count_all, posts.id AS posts_id FROM "posts" INNER JOIN favorites ON posts.id = favorites.favorited_id GROUP BY posts.id ORDER BY "posts"."created_at" DESC, favorite_count desc LIMIT ?
```

How is favorites.count not a column? I've also used posts.favorites.count many, many times to display the favorites counts on posts in ERB but it doesn't work here...

thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went ahead and added the column using this: ryan.mcgeary.org/2016/02/05/… and it worked really well and I can call: `Post.unscoped.order('posts.favorites_count desc').limit(10)`

Answer (score 0):

This error says that SQLite can't `favorite_count` column in `order by` block. If you rewrite `order by` `favorite_count` in the explicit way it will work:

```
Post.
  joins('INNER JOIN favorites ON posts.id = favorites.favorited_id').
  select('posts.*, COUNT(favorites.favorited_id) AS favorite_count').
  group('posts.id').
  order('COUNT(favorites.favorited_id) desc').limit(10)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but this is the SQL that's gets put out (I use only the 'posts.id' here for simplicity):<br/> `SELECT  posts.id, COUNT(favorites.favorited_id) FROM "posts" INNER JOIN favorites ON posts.id = favorites.favorited_id GROUP BY posts.id ORDER BY COUNT(favorites.favorited_id) desc LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 10]]`<br/> and this is the result:<br/>`=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Post id: 206>, #<Post id: 293>, #<Post id: 296>, #<Post id: 322>, #<Post id: 331>, &c` Why does it still sort by "post.created_at"? Why still no counts for the favorites?

Comment: By default ruby's print does not show custom columns as `favorite_count`. Try `posts = Post.joins('INNER JOIN favorites ON posts.id = favorites.favorited_id').select('posts.*, COUNT(favorites.favorited_id) AS favorite_count').group('posts.id').order('COUNT(favorites.favorited_id) desc').limit(10); posts.each { |p| puts "id: #{p.id}, favorite_count: #{p.favorite_count}, created_at: #{p.created_at}" }`. May be `created_at` order and count order are the same for your data.

Comment: do i need to add a column "favorites_count" to the Post model?

Comment: You don't need to add `favorites_count` to the Post model. If a column was in a sql query, `favorites_count` in your case, Rails allow to call `favorites_count` at the result record objects.

Comment: I went ahead and added the column using this: http://ryan.mcgeary.org/2016/02/05/proper-counter-cache-migrations-in-rails/ and it worked really well and I can call: `Post.select('posts.id, posts.favorites_count').order('posts.favorites_count)` but it still renders `ORDER BY "posts"."created_at" DESC, posts.favorites_count`. How do i override the default order scope?

Comment: **HERE IS THE ANSWER TO THE WHOLE THING:** Post.unscoped.order('posts.favorites_count desc').limit(10); thank you, @Ilya Lavrov